# Regex performance in .NET vs Java

Tags: java, .net, regex

I am struggling with regex performance issue while parsing large text files.
I am using .NET 4.0 with the following code:

```
private static pattern =   
@"((\D|^)(19|20|)\d\d([- /.\\])(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])\4(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[0-9])  (\D|$))|" +
@"((\D|^)(19|20|)\d\d([- /.\\])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[0-9])\11(0[1-9]|1[012]|[0-9])  (\D|$))|" + 
@"((\D|^)(0[1-9]|1[012]|[0-9])([- /.\\])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[0-9])\18(19|20|)\d\d(\D|$))|" + 
@"((\D|^)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[0-9])([- /.\\])(0[1-9]|1[012]|[0-9])\25(19|20|)\d\d(\D|$))|" + 
@"((\D|^)(19|20|)\d\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\D|$))|" + 
@"((\D|^)(19|20|)\d\d(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\D|$))|" + 
@"((\D|^)(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(19|20|)\d\d(\D|$))|" + 
@"((\D|^)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(19|20|)\d\d(\D|$))|" + 
@"((^|(?<!(\d[- /.\\\d])|\d))(19|20|)\d\d([- /.\\])(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])([^- /.\\\d\w]|$|\s))|" + 
@"((^|(?<!(\d[- /.\\\d])|\d))(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])([- /.\\])(19|20|)\d\d([^- /.\\\d\w]|$|\s))|" + 
@"((^|(?<!(\d[- /.\\\d])|\d))(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])([- /.\\])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([^- /.\\\d\w]|$|\s))|" + 
@"((^|(?<!(\d[- /.\\\d])|\d))(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.\\])(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])([^- /.\\\d\w]|$|\s))"; 

private static Regex dateRegex = new new Regex(pattern, 
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);

public static void Extract(string text)  
{
   foreach (Match match in dateRegex.Matches(text))
                Console.Writeline("Match {0}",match.Value);
}
```

The processing time for a 1MB text file which includes 200 matches is ~22secs.
Running the same regex with Java produce a much faster result: ~13Secs.
I managed to reduce the processing time of the .NET code by splitting the regex to parts and parallelize its execution.
Why Java is much faster processing this regex?
What can I do to improve the .NET performance processing this regex?

Cheers,
Doron

Comment: This probably doesn't make much of a difference, but have you tried simply executing `dateRegex.Matched(text)` without writing to console?

Comment: What exactly is the pattern matching? If possible, you should consider DFA based parser or a parser for a subset of context free languages. Ex fslex (and fsyacc)

Comment: Would it make sense to iterate through the string then apply your regex to the next ten (or so) characters each time you encounter a digit?

Comment: What happens if you remove the compile action, you only need that if you reuse the expression.

Comment: If you really care about performance, its usually best to avoid using regex, even in Java.  Usually you can write 10x faster without.

Comment: With an NFA engine, regex can be fast or slow, depending on how you craft the expression. The definitive work on this subject: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!"), dedicates a lot of time describing how to craft an accurate and efficient regex. (Hands down, the most useful book I've ever read.) Looking at your expression, I can already see some problems. I'm working on an answer for you right now...

Comment: Splitting the regexp up and paralizing the execution could be a really good answer. What you currently have is an unreadable regular expression that tries to do all. Optimizing it will make it even less readable. For instance, you could try and find some "fingerprint" of a date, then check if it is really a date.

Comment: When doing your timings, are you compiling in release mode and executing without the debugger attached? If you're in Visual Studio, use `Ctrl+F5` to run without debugging, or select "Start Without Debugging" from the Debug menu. If you run with the debugger attached, your timings are not particularly reliable.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No its not the avoidance of regex, its the not understanding of how to properly create a regex. See my articles
<a href="http://omegacoder.com/?p=324">Are C# .Net Regular Expressions Fast Enough for You?</a>
[.Net Regex: Can Regular Expression Parsing be Faster than XmlDocument or Linq to Xml?][2]

[2]: http://omegacoder.com/?p=850

Comment: [Are C# .Net Regular Expressions Fast Enough for You?](http://omegacoder.com/?p=324)
        

[.Net Regex: Can Regular Expression Parsing be Faster than XmlDocument or Linq to Xml?](http://omegacoder.com/?p=850)

Comment: @OmegaMan The question does specificity ask for a comparison of Regex performance Java vs C# I missed you comparison with Java.  It always dangerous to claim to know with is in the OP's mind because it can sound like you want to the question to suit what interests yourself.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No, I just believe your statement that "Usually you can write 10x faster without." is patently false. Most situations using the regex parser shows only 5-40 milleseconds of processesor difference. Which I referenced in my articles.

Comment: @OmegaMan In Java, you would normally ignore the first 10,000 runs as it will not be fully compiled.  How long did it take to perform the next 10,000 on average?

Comment: @OmegaMan I thought it might have something to do with warmup, but it doesn't appear to be the case. Perhaps this is a difference between Java and C# as I get 2.8x to 15x depending on the test in Java. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/01/regex-vs-indexof-in-java.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey which Java regex parser are you using? Thx!

Comment: @OmegaMan The built in regex which may not be the fastest available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different flavors of regex parsers out there and the java one may be more suited for the pattern you use. But your pattern an the options you have choosen really slow this one down!

**RegexOptions.IgnoreCase**  (is this necessary?) [See Want faster regular expressions? Maybe you should think about that IgnoreCase option...](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/archive/2004/03/20/93379.aspx)

**RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace** : You have ZERO pattern whitespace. This does not slow down the actual regex parsing, for it is only to allow the user to document the pattern. But it is telling because it shows that the creator of the pattern (**no offense here really** :-) ) does not understand what the regex parser needs to effectivly execute a pattern in a reasonable amounht of time; *see next statement as to why its slow*.

Your pattern is **slow** because of the ambiguity of the pattern causes too many backtracking issues; plain and simple.

See [Backtracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4.aspx) for more information on what that means.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

I don't have time to complete my analysis right now, but I will provide my progress so far. Here is your regex reformatted so that you can actually read it. The only change that I made was to wrap some spaces in a character class to allow for free-spacing mode. There are 80 capture groups (Yipes! - most of which appear to unnecessary). This expression appears to be matching various forms of a Date. There are many rooms for improvement:

```cs
private static pattern = @"
    # Match various forms of a Date.
      (                                     # Begin $1:
        (\D|^)                              # $2:
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $3:
        ([- /.\\])                          # $4:
        (0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])               # $5:
        \4
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[0-9])      # $6:
        [ ][ ]
        (\D|$)                              # $7:
      )                                     # End $1:
    | (                                     # Begin $8:
        (\D|^)                              # $9:
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $10:
        ([- /.\\])                          # $11:
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[0-9])      # $12:
        \11
        (0[1-9]|1[012]|[0-9])               # $13:
        [ ][ ]
        (\D|$)                              # $14:
      )                                     # End $8:
    | (                                     # Begin $15:
        (\D|^)                              # $16:
        (0[1-9]|1[012]|[0-9])               # $17:
        ([- /.\\])                          # $18:
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[0-9])      # $19:
        \18
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $20:
        (\D|$)                              # $21:
      )                                     # End $15:
    | (                                     # Begin $22:
        (\D|^)                              # $23:
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[0-9])      # $24:
        ([- /.\\])                          # $25:
        (0[1-9]|1[012]|[0-9])               # $26:
        \25
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $27:
        (\D|$)                              # $28:
      )                                     # End $22:
    | (                                     # Begin $29:
        (\D|^)                              # $30:
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $31:
        (0[1-9]|1[012])                     # $32:
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])            # $33:
        (\D|$)                              # $34:
      )                                     # End $29:
    | (                                     # Begin $35:
        (\D|^)                              # $36:
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $37:
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])            # $38:
        (0[1-9]|1[012])                     # $39:
        (\D|$)                              # $40:
      )                                     # End $35:
    | (                                     # Begin $41:
        (\D|^)                              # $42:
        (0[1-9]|1[012])                     # $43:
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])            # $44:
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $45:
        (\D|$)                              # $46:
      )                                     # End $41:
    | (                                     # Begin $47:
        (\D|^)                              # $48:
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])            # $49:
        (0[1-9]|1[012])                     # $50:
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $51:
        (\D|$)                              # $52:
      )                                     # End $47:
    | (                                     # Begin $53:
        ( ^                                 # Begin $54:
        | (?<!
            (\d[- /.\\\d])                  # $55:
          | \d
          )
        )                                   # End $54:
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $56:
        ([- /.\\])                          # $57:
        (0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])               # $58:
        ([^- /.\\\d\w]|$|\s)                # $59:
      )                                     # End $53:
    | (                                     # Begin $60:
        ( ^                                 # Begin $61:
        | (?<!
            (\d[- /.\\\d])                  # $62:
          | \d
          )
        )                                   # End $61:
        (0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])               # $63:
        ([- /.\\])                          # $64:
        (19|20|)\d\d                        # $65:
        ([^- /.\\\d\w]|$|\s)                # $66:
      )                                     # End $60:
    | (                                     # Begin $67:
        ( ^                                 # Begin $68:
        | (?<!
            (\d[- /.\\\d])                  # $69:
          |\d
          )
        )                                   # End $68:
        (0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])               # $70:
        ([- /.\\])                          # $71:
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])            # $72:
        ([^- /.\\\d\w]|$|\s))               # $73:
    | (                                     # Begin $74:
        ( ^                                 # Begin $75:
        | (?<!
            (\d[- /.\\\d])                  # $76:
          | \d
          )
        )                                   # End $75:
        (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])            # $77:
        ([- /.\\])                          # $78:
        (0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])               # $79:
        ([^- /.\\\d\w]|$|\s)                # $80:
      )                                     # End $74:
    ";
```

When I get some more time, I'll update this answer with some recommended improvements. In the meantime, other regex experts please feel free to take this improved partially-commented version and run with it...